# Image capture at the time of windows login

Tags: c#, security, windows-7, webcam, systems-programming

I want to know how i can capture image from webcam when a user success or unsuccessfully make login attempt in windows. Is any `API` for .net available for this purpose or any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u are able to capture image from the webcam then this can help you 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184.aspx

Comment: You link is to `LogonUser`, a function to impersonate a user. How does this relate to the initial question?

Comment: also look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=VS.80%29.aspx